# OIDC: UserInfo for non-users

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

...and yes I understand the title itself is flawed!

Currently I have a system which uses info from the /userinfo endpoint to decide whether to allow them access to particular resources.

E.g. Only allow members with and attribute of company=X are allowed to access company X's resources

This works fine.  However, now I want to allow a machine to access company X's resources (with no user involved).  If I create a service account and gain an access token using a client credentials grant, then there will be no corresponding userinfo (as there is no user).

My question is - what is the correct way to allow a machine access to company X's data?

Note:  Companies (in this example) are not a fixed list.  They can be added dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mean a machine, I assume you have a client application that runs on a machine. And this client require to obtain tokens and consume a resource.

In terms of OAuth 2.0, end user is not necessary to obtain tokens. This is what you see when using client credential grant. Also, user information endpoint is defined by OpenID Connect. In OpenID Connect, each flow involves end user interaction (end user authentication).

You have two options

1. Use [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)

Here you create a user specific to mentioned machine and share the password of it with the client. This user is special, which means it is not a human. You may further define rules for this type of user

2. Use [Client Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4)

You will not get any help with user information endpoint. But you will have to trust access token and allow access of resources. For example, this is anonymous access. Special set of resources will accept this and these resources will not be owned by any user.

Comment: Thanks Kavindu. While it's not the answer I was hoping for, it's the answer I was expecting. Seems like a gap in authentication protocols though (personal opinion). I get to make decisions based on the identity of a user, but can't apply the same logic to a machine.